# sql query - proper way to get id from a string?

Tags: sql

I have a customer table, which has a field "categories".  It's a string holding IDs divided by commas like `1,11,14,21`.

Let's say I want to query all customers which have categoryID 1 - what's the proper way to query it?

The problem is that ID 1 could be at the beginning, middle or the end of the string, or even be the only ID so I'd have to cover all cases like:

```
WHERE categories LIKE '1' 
   OR categories LIKE '1%,' 
   OR categories LIKE '%,1,%' 
   OR categories like '%,1'
```

Is there a more elegant (and probably much faster) way to do this?

Comment: For what database?  The real solution is to **not** store information like this, and use a proper many-to-many table setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead have a CustomerCategories table which has CustomerID, CategoryID columns, and then have one entry per customers category.  This is *far* easier to query - and is very extremely highly the norm for relational databases.

Storing arrays of IDs in strings is non-relational and as you've found is a nightmare to query.

Comment: Not even "much more the norm", rather "THE norm".

Answer (score 2):

You should strangle the person who designed the DB to work like that. Never can I think of an instance where you should have delimited data in a field.

On that note, I think this will be a suitable workaround for you.

```
WHERE ','+[categories]+',' LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Comment: Slow, due to not having the benefit of any index.

Comment: @Amadan: Oh I'm sure it's especially inefficient... but so is the way that the data is stored.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I might not have been clear. It was not any criticism of you, but of the method; I felt free that if the OP chose this approach, he should know the repercussions. I completely agree with everything you wrote.